Swap K and T not working
I'm trying to swap the K and T keys. T should give me help, K should do "till (backwards)"
Moreover, the help command only makes sense in normal mode; the till action makes sense in normal, visual, and operator-pending mode.
So, my mapping file looks like this:
vim.keymap.set('n', 'T', 'K', { noremap = true, desc = 'Help' })
vim.keymap.set('', 'K', 'T', { noremap = true, desc = 'Till (backwards)' })

However, this only partially works: in visual and operator-pending more, K does the correct action (=till backwards).
But in normal mode, K still gives help, instead of performing the "till backwards" action. And the T behaviour is strange: it gives an error man.lua: no manual entry for XXX (with "XXX" the keyword the cursor is on) - it seems like it's trying to give help, but can't? Not sure.
I tried replacing the modes ('n' to '' and vice versa), I tried removing the noremap field, replace it with remap, both with false and true, etc, but the behaviour's never what I'm aiming for.

edit The output of :verbose nmap K:
n  K           *@<Lua 113: /opt/homebrew/Cellar/neovim/0.9.5/share/nvim/runtime/lua/vim/lsp/buf.lua:40>
                 LSP: Hover Documentation
        Last set from Lua
   K           * T
                 Till (backward)
        Last set from Lua

...does this mean that my setting for K is overwritten by the lsp? If yes, is there a way to prevent this from happening?
--> edit: the answer was "yes", and I found (and removed) that line in the LSP config, which fixed the issue.

According to the NeoVim docs, the parameter is called remap. Anyhow, its default value (false) is what you want, here.

Do you have still something open in your question? How can we help you further? Otherwise maybe could you accept one of the solution using the v button next to the arrow voting buttons. It allow the question to rest :-)

I would do:
vim.keymap.set('n', 'T', 'K', { remap = false, desc = 'Help' })
vim.keymap.set('n', 'K', 'T', { remap = false, desc = 'Till (backwards)' })

The documentation about remap is confusing but after many tests (see this answer) I confirm that the parameter to use is remap (and not noremap)
Or just:
vim.keymap.set('n', 'T', 'K', { desc = 'Help' })
vim.keymap.set('n', 'K', 'T', { desc = 'Till (backwards)' })

Since remap is assumed false by default in Neovim.
In your case the K mapping is hidden for some buffers by a buffer mapping probably set when the filetype is set.
You could override the behavior with the following code:
vim.api.nvim_create_autocmd({ 'FileType' }, {
    pattern = {'*'},
    command="nnoremap <buffer> K T"
})

Remark: Replace the '*' by a list of filetypes is you want this to apply to only some of the filetypes.
To override the lua specific mapping a safer method would be that add a ~/.config/nvim/after/ftplugin/lua.lua with the following content:
vim.keymap.set('n', 'K', 'T', { buffer = true, desc = 'Till (backwards)'})

It is safer because it is executed after the normal plugin code is executed. If the mapping is set by a plugin code this is the best way to override the mapping.
Remark: The new T mapping will be bound to K that is bound to the general K behavior and not to the buffer specific K mapping set by LSP.

Thanks for your answer, but I'm having the same issue when I use it. Does it work for you? If so, I'll have to dig deeper in my own config.

It works fine for me (remark T has to be combined with another char so now K has to be combined with another char). I would be interested to the result of :verbose nmap K and :verbose nmap T. It would be that your mapping are overridden by some buffer mappings.

Some filetypes and plugins map K instead of setting helpprg, which I think is a mistake, but it may be causing the normal mode issues.

Hey @VivianDeSmedt, I think you might be right; I've added the output to my question.

Thanks for the feedback. As I feared the K mapping is indeed hidden by a buffer specific mapping (identified with the @ mark). This is probably set (at least in my version of Neovim for the python buffers) when the filetype is set. I have proposed a new version that go around the original limitation.

Thanks for that. I've added the snippet to the end of my keymap.lua file. In text files the K key now works as till(backwards), but in my lua files, it still gives help... could it be the keymap file is loaded too soon i.e. that I must move the snippet to a file that is executed later?

This indeed is probably the case. I don't know when your keymap.lua file is executed (maybe you could tell us more about your setup). I'll make another suggestion in the answer ;-)

Yeah I see the keymap is loaded first, and then the plugins. So I guess that's what causes that. I'll put it in a polish.lua file and let you know how things went

What is the filetype for which you have the problem? If it is a Lua file you should probably plut the code is lua.lua file (polish is probably is misstyping ;-))

The K mapping was indeed overridden by a setting of the LSP. I removed the keymap there, and now all works as expected. Many thanks!

Thanks for the feedback :-)
